# Se agranda automáticamente el tamaño del td en html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jqgrid

Tengo este filtrador general :
[image]

y cuando escribo algo para filtrar se agranda el tamaño del TD automáticamente.

[image]

el codigo js del filtrador es este :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#myBuscador").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#grid tr").filter(function() {
              $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
          });
        });
```

No puedo modificar la clase del td para el tamaño ya que es global y modifica todos los demás td, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

HTML:

```
  <input class="form-control" id="myBuscador" type="text" placeholder="Buscar..">

    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <table id="grid"></table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Grid en jqgrid:

```
function InicializarLista() {
            $("#grid").jqGrid({
                url: '<%=Url.Action("GetList","VE_Propiedades") %>',
                datatype: "json",

                sortable: false,
                colNames: ['Id', 'Dirección', 'Ubicación','Cat Propiedad','Ambientes','Propietario','Operación','Precio','Estado'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 30, editable: false },
                { name: 'CALLE', index: 'CALLE', width: 170, editable: false },
                { name: 'LOCALIDAD', index: 'LOCALIDAD',align: 'center', width: 110, editable: false },
                { name: 'CAT_PROPIETARIO', index: 'CAT_PROPIETARIO',align: 'center', width: 100, editable: false },
                { name: 'AMBIENTES', index: 'AMBIENTES', width: 85,align: 'center', editable: false },
                {name: 'PROPIETARIO', index: 'PROPIETARIO', width: 200, editable: false },
                {name: 'OPERACION', index: 'OPERACION', width: 100,align: 'center', editable: false },
                 { name: 'PRECIO', index: 'PRECIO', width: 85,align: 'center', editable: false },
                {name: 'OBS_PRIVADAS', index: 'OBS_PRIVADAS', width: 230, editable: false },
                ],

                rowNum: 50,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50, 100],
                pager: '#paginador',
                sortname: 'id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",
                scroll: 1,
                width: 1200,
                height: 400,
                multiselect: false,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                editurl: editedRowUrl,

            });
```

El html del debbuger del navegador haciéndole click al elemento de una row de la grilla :

```
    <tr role="row" id="71" tabindex="0" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight" style="display: table-row;" aria-selected="true">
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="71" aria-describedby="grid_ID">71</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="rioja&nbsp;12" aria-describedby="grid_CALLE">rioja&nbsp;12</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="" aria-describedby="grid_LOCALIDAD">&nbsp;</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="PENSION" aria-describedby="grid_CAT_PROPIETARIO">PENSION</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="" aria-describedby="grid_AMBIENTES">&nbsp;</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="prop" aria-describedby="grid_PROPIETARIO">prop</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="Alquiler" aria-describedby="grid_OPERACION">Alquiler</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="1500" aria-describedby="grid_PRECIO">1500</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="" aria-describedby="grid_OBS_PRIVADAS">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

Comment: y porque no agregas otra clase, que deje fijo los tamaños

Comment: ¡Hola Cristian! ¿Podrías compartir también tu HTML para comprobar la estructura?

Comment: Seria bueno que hagas lo que indica Hechi, ver tu codigo html y css que utilizas, ya que el problema radica ahí, que al momento de llamar a tu buscador en javascrip todo css se pierde, y tendrias que añadirlo el javascrip

Comment: En el HTML , EL BUSCADOR:   <input class="form-control" id="myBuscador" type="text" placeholder="Buscar..">
Y LA GRID:
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <table id="grid"></table>
                </div>
  </div>

Comment: les paso las clases "form-control" y "Row" ? o les comparto el html del debugger del navegador?

Comment: Agrega el html completo de la tabla con id `grid` como edición de la pregunta. De otra forma sería difícil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que jqGrid para implementar las tablas utiliza 2 tablas por separado, una para el header y otra para el body:

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <!-- columnas de header con informacion de ancho -->
    </thead>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
       <!-- filas y columnas de datos -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Por lo que todo la manipulacion que hagas en la segunda tabla (de datos) no esta en sintonia con lo que ocurre con el header de la otra.

Para mantener la armonia entre una y otra tabla, jqGrid utiliza una fila oculta en la primera fila de la segunda tabla, del estilo:

```
<tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row" style="height:auto">
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:61px;"></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:141px;"></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:95px;"></td>
</tr>
```

Por lo que para evitar que se rompan los estilos al manipular la segunda tabla, nunca debes tocar esa primera fila, excluyendola de tu selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBuscador").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#grid tr:not(:first-child)").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```